# JSON and jQuery swap json

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have an input field that a user can type in. I'm trying to figure out how I can make the call to json dynamic. So if the person types in printer1, it will use printer1.json. if they type in keyboard5 it will load the keyboard5 json.

Here is my html

```
<input type="text" value="" class="call-json edit-device" />
```

here is my jQuery

```
    $.getJSON('json/printer1.json', function (data) {

        var items = [];
        $.each(data[0].attributes['edgebox.stat.prop.type'], function (key, val) {
            items.push(val);
        });
        displaySortLabel(items, "type-details");

        var items = [];
        $.each(data[0].attributes['edgebox.stat.prop.serial.number'], function (key, val) {
            items.push(val);
        });
        displaySortLabel(items, "serial-number-details");
```

Comment: `$.getJSON('json/'+filename+'.json'`?

Comment: how could I make that +filename+ synch up to what the user types into the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `keyup` event.

```
var timeout = '';
$('.call-json').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var val = this.value;
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $.getJSON('json/'+val+'.json', function (data) {
           // ...
        });       
    }, 80);
})
```

Comment: Good call on debouncing the event before the AJAX call!

Comment: that calls it up on each letter, what if I want to wait till the user has completed the string camera1 and then hits enter?

Comment: Then check to see if the user pressed enter before doing anything.  Or increase the timeout time.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks. @ndesign11, no, not exactly on each keyup, I have used `setTimeout`, as Rocket Hazmet says you can increase the timeout time.